# How does Wolfram Mathematica solve curve fitting problems?

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, curve-fitting, least-squares

Is wolfram mathematica able to find type of curve ? If yes , what function is used ? Also is there any function to solve least square problems in matrices ?

I tried to find some functions in the wolfram Mathematica documentation yet, I couldn't find a suitable one.

Comment: Here is a summary: 
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CurveFittingAndApproximateFunctions.html
Which one did you tried with what parameters? Please be more specific.

Comment: Nothing built-in that explores curve types like https://mycurvefit.com